# Let $(E; d)$ be a metric space. Let $A;B \subseteq E$ be nonempty disjoint subsets and suppose A is compact and B is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that the sets $A$ and $B$ have a positive distance, i.e. show:

$d(A, B) := \inf \{\,d(a, b) : a \in  A, b \in B\} > 0$

I've tried to show this but I couldn't succeed. Basically I was trying to derive a contradiction to $A$ and $B$ being disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

For each $x\in A$, we have $d(x,B)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in B\}>0$ because $x\not\in B$ and $B$ is closed.

Moreover, the function $x\mapsto d(x,B)$ is continuous (this essentially follows from the triangle inequality), and since $A$ is compact, it must attain its minimum. Therefore there is some $x_0\in A$ such that
$$ d(A,B)=d(x_0,B)>0$$

The compactness of $A$ is essential, as the example $A=\{(x,0):x\geq0\}$ and $B=\{(x,\frac{1}{x}):x>0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ shows.