# A problem in analysis involving compactness 1.2.4

Tags: real-analysis

Define $dist(E,F)=inf\{|x-y|:x \in E, y \in F\}$. Let $E,F \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be disjoint closed sets, with at least one of $E$, $F$ being compact. Show that $$dist(E,F)>0$$
Give a counter example to show that this claim fails when the compactness hypothesis is dropped.

$\textbf{My approach}:$ Since $E,F$ are closed, they are same as their respective closures, i.e. $\overline{E}=E, \overline{F}=F$. Since $E,F$ are disjoint, $E \cup F=\phi$. Hence $\overline{E} \cup \overline{F}=\phi$. Thus there is no common limit point shared by $E$ and $F$. Hence $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $inf\{|x-y|:x \in \overline{E}, y \in \overline{F}\}>\epsilon,$ for otherwise, we would have common limit points shared by $\overline{E}$ and $\overline{F}$. Thus $\exists \epsilon>0,$ such that $dist(\overline{E},\overline{F})>\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists \epsilon>0,$ such that $dist(E,F)>\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $dist(E,F)>0$.

$\textbf{The problem}:$ Where does the compactness of at least one of the sets $E,F$ fit in? And how do I construct the counter example?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Problem reference: Exercise $1.2.4 ~(p.25)$ from "An introduction to measure theory" by Terry Tao.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955447/let-e-d-be-a-metric-space-let-ab-subseteq-e-be-nonempty-disjoint-subse

Comment: You should note that even if two sets can have no common limit point, they could have distance zero.
Consider two closed sets $\{xy \geq 1\}, \{x=0\}$ in the plane, both are not compact.